# jushed.exe runs without confirmation on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, java, updates, administrator

`Jushed.exe` is put a prompt on every system start.

I want to handle it as Windows XP handled: silently.

What can I do to force the silent mode?
I set the `.exe` properties to "run as admin" but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I'd just disable jushed.exe in stead of going though the effort. It's not like it's an important proces or anything, all it does is slow down your system. It's the Java quickstarter (or updater), wich doesn't need to run at startup unless you use Java **very** often.
Anyway, it's your PC, so I'll leave the choice to you.

---

### Disabling it

Press the following key combination: `[Flag] + [R]`.
In the dialog that pops up, type `msconfig` and click the OK button.
If needed, grant administrator privileges.
Go to the startup tab in the new dialog that's just popped up, and search for `jushed.exe`.
Once you found it, uncheck the box in front of it. Close the `msconfig` dialog by clicking the **OK** button, then reboot your computer.
Once rebooted, you will probably get a dialog telling you something about the system configuration having changed, click the checkbox to tell it to not display this dialog again on the next boot, and click the OK button.

### Automatically granting it administrator privileges

There are two ways of doing this.
Create a whitelist and put `jushed.exe` on it. This is explained here: http://www.beingmanan.com/wp/2008/06/create-uac-white-list/ 
Or you can just disable *UAC* to just skip the "grant privileges" box for every proces: http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/

Comment: you didnt answer the question...

Comment: I did. You were asking how to skip the "grant privileges" box `jushed.exe` gives you every time you start your computer, right? Well, I gave you three ways to fix it.